# How to assert HTTP request is made with correct URI when using VCR and WebMock?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vcr, webmock

I am testing a Ruby on Rails project using WebMock and VCR. I would like to assert that a request is made to the correct host, but I can't find an example of how to do that. Here's some pseudo-code for what I'm trying to do:

```
VCR.use_cassette('example.com request') do
  subject.domain = 'example.com'
  expect { subject.get('/something') }.to make_a_get_request_for('http://example.com/something')
end
```

Comment: VCR is awesome for recording/playing, but why do you need VCR then if you just want to set an expectation on a request?

Comment: Good point. I think I was trying to test too many things in one test. I can create a separate test that does not use VCR to test the request with WebMock.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your VCR is recording to YAML (the default, I believe?), this one-liner returns an array of HTTP URIs that were called during the current cassette block:

```rb
YAML.load_file(VCR.current_cassette.file)["http_interactions"].pluck("request").pluck("uri")
```

E.g.,

```rb
YAML.load_file(VCR.current_cassette.file)["http_interactions"].pluck("request").pluck("uri")
[
    [0] "https://stackoverflow.com/wayland-project/libinput/e0008d3d/tools/libinput-debug-gui.c",
    [1] "https://stackoverflow.com/wayland-project/libinput"
]
```

You can use an array matching method of your choice to assert the expected request URI from there.

Other members of the `request` object you might want to `pluck` instead of `uri`:

```rb
{
         "method" => "get",
            "uri" => "https://stackoverflow.com/adomain",
           "body" => {
            "encoding" => "US-ASCII",
              "string" => ""
        },
        "headers" => {
           "Accept" => [
          ...
        }
}
```